# SQL pivot with more than one aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

``
I have a table which shows data for each of the dates on a column. The variable date_data is the date where the simulation was done, id and name identify a user, T are all the future dates where values are simulated and value are the random simulated values.

SQL so far:

```
 select *
    from (select date_data,id, name, scenery, 
                 (extract(month from date)-extract(month from data_date))+12*(extract(year from date)-extract(year from data_date)) as T, value   
            from escen
            where date_data = '30/09/2022'
              and scenario in ('BASE')
          )    
    pivot ( avg(value) 
            for T between 0 and 120
    order by 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

This returns a pivoted table with the average value of the 3 different IDs.

Data:

```
date_data|ID|Name|Scenery|N Simu|Simul|   Date   | Value
30/09/22 |1|  A  |  Base | 1000 |  1  | 30/09/28 | 0,0397
30/09/22 |1|  A  |  Base | 1000 |  2  | 30/09/28 | -0,069
```

I have different Scenarios and 1000 simulations for each of those. The simul column shows which number of simulation is of these 1000, and I want to get the avg, max, min and stddev of these 1000 simulations for each ID in each date.

Current results:

```
date_data|ID|Name|Scenery |     30/09/28     |   31/10/28
30/09/22 |1|  A  |  Base  |    avg(value)    |  avg(value)
30/09/22 |2|  B  |  Base  |    avg(value)    |  avg(value)
30/09/22 |3|  C  |  Base  |    avg(value)    |  avg(value)
```

With the query above, I am able to get the functions, but one by one. I would like to add an extra column that returned which function is showing, and get the 4 results in the same output instead of having 4 different outputs.

Desired results:

```
date_data|Function|ID|Name|Scenery |     30/09/28     |  31/10/28
30/09/22 |Average |1|  A  |  Base  |    avg(value)    |  avg(value)
30/09/22 |Minimum |1|  A  |  Base  |    min(value)    |  min(value)
30/09/22 |Maximum |1|  A  |  Base  |    max(value)    |  max(value)
30/09/22 |  Stdev |1|  A  |  Base  |    std(value)    |  std(value)
30/09/22 |Average |2|  B  |  Base  |    avg(value)    |  avg(value)
30/09/22 |Minimum |2|  B  |  Base  |    min(value)    |  min(value)
30/09/22 |Maximum |2|  B  |  Base  |    max(value)    |  max(value)
30/09/22 |  Stdev |2|  B  |  Base  |    std(value)    |  std(value)
30/09/22 |Average |3|  C  |  Base  |    avg(value)    |  avg(value)
30/09/22 |Minimum |3|  C  |  Base  |    min(value)    |  min(value)
30/09/22 |Maximum |3|  C  |  Base  |    max(value)    |  max(value)
30/09/22 |  Stdev |3|  C  |  Base  |    std(value)    |  std(value)
```

Comment: You need to use a combination of `pivot` and `unpivot`: calculate `agg(column)` as separate columns, unpivot them to `funcname, value` columns and then pivot `value` column by date.

Comment: Not too sure on how to do that, but I understand what you mean and now I know how to follow. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
select *
from   (
  select date_data,
         id,
         name,
         scenario, 
         TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, date_data)) as T,
         value   
  from   escen
  where  scenario = 'BASE'
  and    date_data >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -120)
)    
pivot (
  avg(value) AS avg,
  min(value) AS min,
  max(value) AS max,
  stddev(value) AS stddev
  for date_data IN (
    DATE '2022-09-30' AS "2022-09-30",
    DATE '2022-10-01' AS "2022-10-01"
  )
)
unpivot (
  value
  for (type, date_data) IN (
    "2022-09-30_AVG"    AS ('AVG',    DATE '2022-09-30'),
    "2022-09-30_MIN"    AS ('MIN',    DATE '2022-09-30'),
    "2022-09-30_MAX"    AS ('MAX',    DATE '2022-09-30'),
    "2022-09-30_STDDEV" AS ('STDDEV', DATE '2022-09-30'),
    "2022-10-01_AVG"    AS ('AVG',    DATE '2022-10-01'),
    "2022-10-01_MIN"    AS ('MIN',    DATE '2022-10-01'),
    "2022-10-01_MAX"    AS ('MAX',    DATE '2022-10-01'),
    "2022-10-01_STDDEV" AS ('STDDEV', DATE '2022-10-01')
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE escen (date_data, id, name, scenario, value) as
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-30', 1, 'A', 'BASE', LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-30', 2, 'A', 'BASE', LEVEL * 2 + 5 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-10-01', 1, 'A', 'BASE', LEVEL / 2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-10-01', 2, 'A', 'BASE', LEVEL * 2 - 5 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME | SCENARIO | T | TYPE | DATE_DATA | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | BASE | 1 | AVG | 30-SEP-22 | 500.5 |
| 1 | A | BASE | 1 | MIN | 30-SEP-22 | 1 |
| 1 | A | BASE | 1 | MAX | 30-SEP-22 | 1000 |
| 1 | A | BASE | 1 | STDDEV | 30-SEP-22 | 288.819436095749391771367354657669015357 |
| 1 | A | BASE | 1 | AVG | 01-OCT-22 | 250.25 |
| 1 | A | BASE | 1 | MIN | 01-OCT-22 | .5 |
| 1 | A | BASE | 1 | MAX | 01-OCT-22 | 500 |
| 1 | A | BASE | 1 | STDDEV | 01-OCT-22 | 144.409718047874695885683677328834507679 |
| 2 | A | BASE | 1 | AVG | 30-SEP-22 | 1006 |
| 2 | A | BASE | 1 | MIN | 30-SEP-22 | 7 |
| 2 | A | BASE | 1 | MAX | 30-SEP-22 | 2005 |
| 2 | A | BASE | 1 | STDDEV | 30-SEP-22 | 577.638872191498783542734709315338030714 |
| 2 | A | BASE | 1 | AVG | 01-OCT-22 | 996 |
| 2 | A | BASE | 1 | MIN | 01-OCT-22 | -3 |
| 2 | A | BASE | 1 | MAX | 01-OCT-22 | 1995 |
| 2 | A | BASE | 1 | STDDEV | 01-OCT-22 | 577.638872191498783542734709315338030714 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HB_86qrW)

Comment: Even better than what I had in mind! Thank you so much!

Comment: If I wanted to do the same but for a big amount of dates, should I copy/paste the unpivot section with my new dates or is there a way to define all the dates with one line? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Guillem Update both the `PIVOT` and the `UNPIVOT` sections. (There is not an easy way to do it for a large number of values so copy/paste is probably the simplest way to go - although you might be able to write an SQL statement to generate the pivot/unpivot SQL statement...)